# imagepolygon - Generate strange output

Tags: php, image

When try to draw a simple polygon, a strange output happen.

```
<?php
// cria uma imagem em branco
$image = imagecreate(400, 300);

// prenche a cor do fundo
$bg = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

// escolhe uma cor para o poligono
$col_poly = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

// desenha o poligono
imagepolygon($image, 
             array (
                    0, 0,
                    100, 200,
                    300, 200
             ),
             3,
             $col_poly);

// envia a imagem
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image);

?>
```

**The output is:**

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /var/www/drawimage/index.php:2) in /var/www/drawimage/index.php on line 23
```

**what should be the picture looks like this:**

```
‰PNG  IHDR,×ywPLTEÿÿÿ¥ÙŸÝ1IDAThí•;ŽÜ0D5ë¡À€Ç™CÂ±¡à#è(<åÌýùivWeX»+‘P"úa§8ÑYxä7üä‘<ò-ÒÈKhdþÅ#3¦Ä#EÓwy²È?ñÈû‡ŒðÊÈôb‘0}á‘yMH#ïÏáò~V™yû¥òžV™ç:g\Ö+N<8dmE*³"¬2qšXeâñGD&ú¿ÌŠÊ„÷©ÌŠÊ¬¥He¶ï ÙFŸSf¾p¶iá”ÙN™ý‚Ù;QÊì§L\œ21{‚‘í¹ð¥LØž”2;B)³W¢”9¾Bä|F™¹xA9f…Qæ@eÎëM<pälD(s"Œ2q1ÊÄê DŽ÷Â#„2áxÊœ¡ÌYˆPæú‘kìqeæfáæš\™Á•¹/7ñH@‘»¬ÌàÊÄs+••¹VÀÊ„k+s#°2wX™ìD²¡G•™Õ¥™lNPe2U&¿ÚÄ#Cò6 29‚*ï%ªLì¬H¶^xT&dkP™•ÉË€ÊýBŠ‘Ç”™»›nŠ)Á”)L™òb)»@Ê”¦LÌ7˜2ÑØu"ÅnáH™Pì eJR¦¬)Sµ©Qf6·jªA”©D™úZ©›ÊÔ¢L,·ˆ2ÑÙ+‘j¿ð L¨ö€25(S”iº‹‹4ãî+Ó ¾2Í„øÊ4ˆ¯L{©‰G‚‡´=\eZÄW&Ö¾2 â+#ÍÉÂ#®2¡9q•iW™¶†«ŒÒ\DvOñ”QæÃSFA
```

what is happening?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Comment: It looks more as if the gd-libary is not available. You sure you have installed it Hedron ?

Comment: ok, that must be it. Now, how I install gd-library?

Comment: The `‰PNG....` output is a pretty strong indicator that GD is actually installed, no?

Comment: Problem solved guys!!! the header was the problem, its was conflicting with the output $imagepng($image);

Answer (score 0):

problem solved, 
you can see the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php) the header was conflicting with the imagepng($image);

The fixed code:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
// cria uma imagem em branco
$image = imagecreate(400, 300);

// prenche a cor do fundo
$bg = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

// escolhe uma cor para o poligono
$col_poly = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

// desenha o poligono
imagepolygon($image, 
             array (
                    0, 0,
                    100, 200,
                    300, 200
             ),
             3,
             $col_poly);

// put the image out
imagepng($image);

?>
```

just changed the location of the header.